# Check if Json Array is empty or contains one Json Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I check whether

```
{
     "data": [
          {
               "latitude": 12,
               "longitude": 13
          }
     ]
}
```

contains one object, as the previous example, or it is empty, as the following example:

```
{
         "data": [
              []
         ]
}
```

This is my snippet:

```
...
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body());
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the data array length like this:

```
if(jsonArray.length() > 0) { //it means that there is a record in data attr }
```